# How to get the file position of an XSD error in the XML file?

Tags: .net, xml, xsd

I have the following code which successfully validates an XML file against an XSD schema:

```
    Try

        Dim val As New Xml.XmlReaderSettings With {.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema}
        val.Schemas.Add(Nothing, "myvalidator.xsd")

        Using reader = XmlReader.Create("myfile.xml", val)
            While reader.Read
            End While
        End Using

        Console.WriteLine("XML validation succeeded.")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("XML validation failed." & vbCr & vbLf & "Error Message: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

A sample error I'm getting is

```
The element 'address' has invalid child element 'zip_code'. List of possible elements expected: 'address_line_2, address_line_3, city'.
```

When I'm validating a large XML file with hundreds of members who each have several addresses, this isn't enough information to pinpoint the problem. Is there a way to get a line number or file position or some other helpful piece of data to know where exactly the problem is happening in the original XML file? I realize XmlReader isn't reading the file the same way a text reader does, and the XML might be nicely formatted or on one giant line, so line numbers aren't necessarily the way to go. It would seem like I should be able to do something inside the `While` loop to know where the problem is, but I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do not use "ex.Message". It only shows you the text of the top-level exception. Use ex.ToString() instead.

Secondly, look at the properties of the XmlReader at the time of the exception. Also, look carefully at all of the properties of the `XmlException` you are being passed. It has `LineNumber` and `LinePosition` properties.

Comment: Perfect. I had forgotten to trap the specific error type, so I was only looking at the properties for the generic Exception handler, and not the specific XmlSchemaValidationException handler, so I wasn't seeing the extra properties like LineNumber and LinePosition, which are exactly what I need. Thanks!